How to get the list of books that are not borrowed and in stock?
Can anyone help me solve my problem on querying available books? I don't want to allow a user to borrow books that are already borrowed or not yet returned and books that are out of stock based on the number of copies.

I have Book model and books table with number_of_copy column.
I have BorrowRequest model and borrow_requests tables with details of borrower or user.
and I have BorrowRequestItem model and borrow_request_items table with quantity column, which is the number of copies borrowed by the user, and returned_at column to trigger if returned or not.

Now I want to query the books that are being borrowed by the users and books in stock.
$user = 1; // sample user but it is dynamic

if (!$user) {
  return;
}

$availableBooks = \App\Models\Book::where('number_of_copy', '>', 0)
  ->where('is_requestable', true)
  ->whereNull('deleted_at')
  ->whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->select('book_id')
      ->from('borrow_request_items')
      ->join(
        'borrow_requests',
        'borrow_request_items.borrow_request_id',
        '=',
        'borrow_requests.id'
      )
      ->whereColumn('borrow_request_items.book_id', 'books.id')
      ->where('borrow_requests.borrower_user_id', $user)
      ->whereIn('borrow_requests.status', ['Pending', 'Approved'])
      ->whereNull('borrow_request_items.returned_at')
      ->groupBy('book_id')
      ->havingRaw('SUM(borrow_request_items.quantity) >= books.number_of_copy');
    })
  ->get()
  ->pluck('title', 'id')
  ->all();

return $availableBooks;


What is the error you are getting? the code seems correct.
